# When to use had rather

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage

1. I had rather go home than stay out too late.
2. I had rather listen my parents or get in trouble.

Is had rather refers to past?

Can anyone explain 2nd sentence in other words?

Comment: You might also be interested in looking into the somewhat related idioms: *"would rather"* and *"had better/best"*.

Comment: The one I linked has a wonderful explanation.  Enjoy.

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this NGram shows...

[image]

...the form *"I **had** rather..."* is effectively "archaic". In most spoken contexts it's *"**I'd** rather X"*, so you can't really tell what verb form the speaker *thinks* he's contracting, but these days I'm sure it's invariably ***would***.

The usage has nothing to do with references to "the past". The now-standard conditional simply means ***if given a choice***, X is what I would prefer/rather have.

---

OP's first example can thus be "fixed" simply by replacing ***had*** with ***would*** ("If given a choice, I would prefer to go home, not stay out too late").

But example #2 is just completely wrong. Depending on the intended meaning, credible rephrasings might be...

> *"I **had better** listen to my parents **or** I will get into trouble"*
>    *"I **would rather** listen to my parents **than** get into trouble"*.